# Facebook permission rerequest throws oauth exception without a message

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to rerequest declined permission with the facebook api (I'm doing all manually without the sdk). I have read in the docs that I have to make a request with *auth_Type=rerequest* to regather missing permission.

So now I'm doing the following request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URI}&scope=email&auth_type=rerequest
```

And I get the following error:

```
{
  error: {
    message: "",
    type: "OAuthException",
    code: 100,
    fbtrace_id: "FDSHkpgT7iP",
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don’t know where you got that address from, but the current URL of the login dialog is of the format `https://www.facebook.com/v2.11/dialog/oauth?...` -
 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow

Comment: In a post here on stackoverflow someone said that I should use this address and not the dialog. It's working except the rerequest thing. But thank you for the tipp. I will try it. :)

Comment: Re-asking permissions is described a bit further down on the same page, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#reaskperms